# Issue with CSS styles of a Jquery photo gallery

Tags: css, xhtml

Hello to every member of this awesome community!!!
I am currently using a jQuery slider in particular http://www.kyrielles.net/sliderkit/demos/photos-galleries.html , the one with the caption feauture and the thumbnails navigation clip. 
My issue is that when i first tested the gallery was looking perfect, but when i inserted into the startpage of my current project the thumbnail pics of the navigation clip instead of being ordered the one next to the other. They are ordered the one beneath the other. So in the clip i can see only the first thumbnail and the others are hidden. 
The html code is:

```
 <div class="sliderkit photosgallery-captions">
 <div class="sliderkit-nav">
 <div class="sliderkit-nav-clip">
 <!---php for-loop that retrieves the thumbnail pics--->
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#"  rel="nofollow" title="[link title]"><img src="<#IMAGE2#>" alt="[Alternative   text]" /></a></li>
 </ul>
 <!---end of loop--->
 </div>
```

The CSS styles are:

```
   .photosgallery-captions{width:500px;height:335px;padding:0 0 76px;}

   /* Navbar */
   .photosgallery-captions .sliderkit- nav{left:0;bottom:0;width:480px;padding:10px;background:#000;}
  .photosgallery-captions .sliderkit-nav-clip ul li{float:left;margin:0;}
  .photosgallery-captions .sliderkit-nav-clip ul li  a{display:block;width:75px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:3px;}
  .photosgallery-captions .sliderkit-nav-clip ul li.sliderkit-selected a{padding:0;border:3px solid #fff;}

  .sliderkit{display:none;position:relative;overflow:hidden;text-align:left;}
   .sliderkit a,
   .sliderkit a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
   .sliderkit a:focus{outline:1px dotted #000;/*optional*/}
    .sliderkit img{border:0;}

   /*---------------------------------
   *  Navigation
   *---------------------------------*/
  .sliderkit .sliderkit-nav{z-index:10;position:absolute;text-align:center;}

  /* Nav > Clip */
  .sliderkit .sliderkit-nav-clip{position:relative;overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;}
  .sliderkit .sliderkit-nav-clip ul{position:relative;left:0;top:0;list-   style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
  .sliderkit .sliderkit-nav-clip ul li{float:left;}
  .sliderkit .sliderkit-nav-clip ul li a{display:block;overflow:hidden;}
```

When i change the overflow property to visible i can see that all thumbnails exist but in vertical order. 
Any suggestions of what i should change to fix this would be highly appreciated!
Thanks for taking the time reading this...

Answer (score 1):

dropping things in to the li is going to put them in to a verticle order.  What you can do is set up the css to display things in however many columns you want to see.  The column widths will have to total up to less than 100% or one will get pushed down.  Then add a couple of variable in the php for each loop that.  one that determines which column the photo needs to be in (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc)   and set the second to class="float-x" where x is the column the image should be in.   Then you can add that variable to the li tag

for example

```
<style type="text/css">
    .float-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
    .float-2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
    .float-3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
</style>
```

then in the code (this is c# but concept should be similar for php)

```
<ul>
var i = 1;
@foreach(var item in Model.Application)
{
    var classStyle= "";
    if(i==3 || i%3== 0)
    {
        classStyle = "class=float-3";
    }
    else if(i==2 || i%3 == 2)
    {
        classStyle = "class=float-2";
    }
    else if (i==1 || i%3 == 1)
    {
        classStyle = "class=float-1";
    }
 }
 <li @classStyle><a href="#"  rel="nofollow" title="[link title]"><img src="<#IMAGE2#>" alt="[Alternative   text]" /></a></li>
i++;
}
</ul>
```

This works for 3 columns but obviously you can make it for 2 or 4 or any number of columns pretty easily.

Comment: First of all thanx for your answer...I dont understand why the li elements should be dropped in vertical order from the moment i have tested the same php code and css styles in a fresh project and the thumbnails were illustrated in horizontal order. I think the issue is more likely css related.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was...I inserted the clear:none rule to the <li> elements and now the look horizontal. Obviously there was some overwritting of the rule in some other css definition that was setting clear:both.Thnax again Tom for your answer it was helpful to think into the right direction

Comment: ah I was thinking you wanted columns and missed the horizontal display.   yes LI's are going to display vertically by default.   You may be able to do the same with a display inline I believe.   I've done horizontal menus with LI's before it was the display attribute that was the key for those.